# What are these strange entries in IIS 6 logs

Tags: iis, logging

The IIS log is full of entries like this:

```
2013-02-04 20:51:07 31.223.20.153 11435 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:07 78.178.55.210 53836 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:07 86.149.201.150 57616 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:17 86.149.201.150 57600 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:17 72.188.100.193 2480 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:17 65.12.233.165 50176 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:57 135.245.10.6 30739 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:57 135.245.10.6 30906 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:57 135.245.10.6 30905 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-02-04 20:51:57 135.245.10.6 30951 192.168.1.69 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

What do these mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copied from this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtransports/archive/2004/07/15/184336.aspx)

> Timer_ConnectionIdle, happens in normal HTTP protocol usage, where the
>   client decides not to disconnect from the server because there is a
>   good chance that it will have another request for the server either in
>   the process of loading a page or because a client will probably click
>   a link on a web page that will go back to the same server. By default
>   the server will close the connection and reclaim those resources after
>   2 minutes of inactivity. This is nothing to worry about, it's just an
>   informational type of entry

Based on feedback these log entries are not observed in a Win2k8, IIS7 setup.

Comment: I was worried, because I get many logs like this per second.

Comment: @MarioM Hey Mario, I was getting the same thing I would have GIGS of logs every few days with nothing but millions of these entries. I found this fix to prevent the logs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/820729 just add "EnableErrorLogging" dword = 0 to your registry and no more logs. But I'm not sure if I'm suppressing a real issue here should I be closing connections on my end to prevent this? I do get 20+ million hits a day on my server and being it's an API I probably should be closing connections fast.

Comment: @bfritz That is bad advice. You disabled  ALL errorlogging with that setting. Now your customers wonder at one day why you are no longer accepting connections and when you open the log you see....nothing...that would cause increase the resolution time for diagnosing http-errors dramatically...if you go down that route be aware of that consequence. If you want to close connection fast look at tuning tcp/ip sesstion like [TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx)

Comment: I have upgraded to Win2008 server and IIS 7, now I don't have those errors anymore.

Comment: I have 2012 R2+ IIS 8 - but got same error in log.